# What did Kirito say to Asuna while stargazing in the movie "Ordinal Scale"?

Tags: sword-art-online

I just can't figure out what he said. My biggest assumption is "I love you", but that would be too mainstream.

[image: Kirito and Asuna while stargazing]

Comment: The only clue we get is at the beginning of the movie where it starts with a star gazing scene. Unless he is inviting her to star gaze next year since the voice is muted I dont believe we are meant to know. Asuna looks down so probably what he said was embarrassing to her.

Comment: I believe he said "Will you marry me", kinda got it from reading his lips, but that's all I got.